# Scrapy yielding only last url item

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I'm writing a simple web scraper to go through amazon pages and get book details. For this I use Selenium, to get JS generated content. It iterates over the list of ASINs, but only gets the very last ASIN title and book info and repeats it as many times as I have ASINs. I couldn't figure out why `yield` doenst work for each url. Here is the source code:

```py
class BooksSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'books'
    allowed_domains = ['amazon.com']
    # list of ASIN to append to append to URL
    list_url = ['B075QL36RW', 'B01ISNIKES', 'B06XG27KV2', 'B00IWGRPRK', 'B00NS42GFW', 'B0178USZ88', 'B00KWGOBQQ', 'B07FXXM638']

    def start_requests(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
        for url in self.list_url:
            link = f'https://www.amazon.com/dp/{url}'
            self.driver.get(link)
            yield scrapy.Request(link, self.parse_book)


    def parse_book(self, response):
        sel = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)

        title_raw = sel.xpath('//*[@id="productTitle"]/text()').extract()
        info_raw = sel.xpath('//*[@id="bookDescription_feature_div"]/noscript').extract()

        title = ' '.join(''.join(title_raw).split())
        info = ' '.join(''.join(info_raw).split())
        cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>|&([a-z0-9]+|#[0-9]{1,6}|#x[0-9a-f]{1,6});')
        cleantext = re.sub(cleanr, '', info)

        yield {
            'title': title,
            'info': cleantext
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `parse_book()`, you're using `yield` so it's a generator. `start_requests()` is already a generator. So when you loop over the results of `start_requests()`, what you actually get is an iterable (eg, a list) of the generators from `parse_book`. Now, until you iterate over these generators, they are not called or evaluated. When you do finally evaluate it, it's probably *after* getting all the books from `start_requests`; and after the last loop of `parse_book`. At that point, the `self.driver.page_source` in `parse_book` is that of the last one, so 'title' and 'cleantext' are the result of the last iteration, so they only have value of the last book, so that's what you see each time.

If you replace the `yield` with `return` in `parse_book()`, then 'self.driver.page_source', 'title' and 'cleantext', etc. are evaluated with their current loop variables and you'll get different results.

Comment: Tried using ```return```, didn't help. However, I managed to get it working by restructuring code a little. This time ```start_requests()``` parses the url, invokes ```parse_books()```, writes the data down and proceeds to the next url.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how restructuring code helped to solve the problem:

```py
list_of_urls = ['B075QL36RW', 'B01ISNIKES', 'B06XG27KV2', 'B00IWGRPRK', 'B00NS42GFW']
asin = iter(list_of_urls)

def start_requests(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('path/to/driver')
        self.driver.get('https://amazon.com/dp/B06xt7gkb1')

        sel = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
        url = 'https://amazon.com/dp/B06xt7gkb1'
        yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_book)

        while True:
            next_url = f'https://amazon.com/dp/{next(self.asin)}'
            self.driver.get(next_url)
            sel = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
            yield Request(next_url, callback=self.parse_book)

    def parse_book(self, response):
        ...
```